# SQL Server: detect inventory changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, inventory, stock

I have a simple inventory table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#t') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #t
GO

CREATE TABLE #t
(
    [date] DATE,
    Item VARCHAR(1),
    [Location] INT,
    Qty INT
)

INSERT INTO #t ([date], [Item], [Location], [Qty]) 
VALUES ('2017-11-16', 'A', 1, 5),
       ('2017-11-16', 'B', 1, 5),
       ('2017-11-16', 'B', 2, 10),
       ('2017-11-16', 'A', 3, 1),
       ('2017-11-16', 'C', 3, 2),
       ('2017-11-16', 'A', 4, 20),
       ('2017-11-15', 'A', 1, 5),
       ('2017-11-15', 'B', 1, 5),
       ('2017-11-15', 'B', 2, 10),
       ('2017-11-15', 'A', 3, 1),
       ('2017-11-15', 'C', 3, 8),
       ('2017-11-14', 'A', 1, 10),
       ('2017-11-14', 'B', 1, 1),
       ('2017-11-14', 'B', 2, 10),
       ('2017-11-14', 'A', 3, 1),
       ('2017-11-14', 'C', 3, 8)
```

I would like to find out the date (in the where clause) and also the difference in quantity of a location-item-level for the past.

Thus the result should be as follows:

```
+------------+------+----------+-----+------------+---------+
|    Date    | Item | Location | Qty | LastChange | LastQty |
+------------+------+----------+-----+------------+---------+
| 16.11.2017 | A    |        1 |   5 | 14.11.2017 |      10 |
| 16.11.2017 | B    |        1 |   5 | 14.11.2017 |       1 |
| 16.11.2017 | B    |        2 |  10 |            |         |
| 16.11.2017 | A    |        3 |   1 |            |         |
| 16.11.2017 | C    |        3 |   2 | 15.11.2017 |       8 |
| 16.11.2017 | A    |        4 |  20 |            |         |
+------------+------+----------+-----+------------+---------+
```

Since the inventory table is quite big I would like to avoid windowed-functions if possible.

I have self-joined the inventory table. However, I have problems to find a clause for eliminating the irrelevant data sets.

```
SELECT
    a.[date],
    a.Item,
    a.Location,
    a.qty,
    b.[date] LastChange,
    b.qty LastQty
FROM 
    #t a
LEFT JOIN 
    #t b ON a.Item = b.Item 
         AND a.location = b.location  
         AND b.date < a.date
WHERE   
    a.date = '2017-11-16'
```

Comment: Windowed function can be more efficient than using subqueries. Look for pivot to do this.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Also, window functions were introduced to increase performance for cases like this, so why not using a window function?

Comment: Fair enough, if this has a positive impact than I am prone to use them. Server Version is 11.0.6598.0. Thank you :-)

Comment: @JeanDoux : You mean using the pivot function in MSSQL? Wouldn't that work on only one column to pivot?

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional `LEFT JOIN` in order to eliminate redundant records:

```
SELECT a.[date], a.Item, a.Location, a.qty,
       b.[date] LastChange, b.qty LastQty
FROM t AS a
LEFT JOIN t AS b 
   ON a.Item = b.Item AND a.location = b.location AND b.date < a.date AND a.qty != b.qty
LEFT JOIN t AS c 
   ON c.Item = b.Item AND c.location = b.location AND c.date < b.date    
WHERE   
    a.[date] = '2017-11-16' AND c.Item IS NULL
```

Using

```
LEFT JOIN t AS c 
   ON c.Item = b.Item AND c.location = b.location AND c.date < b.date
```

combined with

```
WHERE   
    ... AND c.Item IS NULL
```

is like saying: get me those `b` records having no other, `c`, record with an earlier date.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/CDI88385)

Using `FIRST_VALUE` window function:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [date], [Item], [Location], [Qty],
           FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item], [Location] 
                                     ORDER BY [date]) AS LastChange,
           FIRST_VALUE([Qty]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Item], [Location] 
                                    ORDER BY [date]) AS LastQty
    FROM t
)
SELECT [date], [Item], [Location], [Qty],
       IIF([Qty] != [LastQty], LastChange, NULL) AS LastChange,
       IIF([Qty] != [LastQty], LastQty, NULL) AS LastQty
FROM CTE
WHERE [date] = '2017-11-16'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/389c7/9)

Comment: Thank you. Learned a lot here. The windowed functions are indeed must faster! Thank you.

Comment: There is one problem however when using FIRST_VALUE. There is no detection in intermediate changes. In you demo you can see this with the C article. The last change should be 15.11. not 14.11.

Comment: @rasenkantenstein So you want to detect the *latest* record in this case? What if you have multiple changes, like `('2017-11-16', 'C', 3, 2)`, ` `('2017-11-16', 'C', 3, 8)`,  `('2017-11-16', 'C', 3, 5)`?

Comment: Hi Giorgos, exactly. The Date of the previous change and the amount of that change. This is a snapshot table being create once a day, the primary key is date+location+item. Only one state is possible. However the windowed functions were indeed very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
DECLARE @ReportDate date='20171116'

SELECT
  curData.[date],
  curData.Item,
  curData.Location,
  curData.Qty,
  lastData.[date] LastChange,
  lastData.Qty LastQty
FROM
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM #t
    WHERE [date]=@ReportDate
  ) curData
OUTER APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #t lastData
    WHERE lastData.Item=curData.Item
      AND lastData.Location=curData.Location
      AND lastData.[date]<curData.[date]
      AND lastData.Qty<>curData.Qty
    ORDER BY lastData.[date] DESC
  ) lastData
```

Comment: I changed my answer. In my first version I forgot to use the condition `lastData.Qty<>curData.Qty`

Comment: Hi, I have never really used the concept apply so far. I might want to explore this further. Thank you!

Comment: @rasenkantenstein - SQL is amazing language. I wish you success on this way!